# How to get a list of elements in espresso?

Tags: java, android, selenium, android-espresso

I'm trying to automate an android native app using espresso framework and i can't find a way how to get list of elements. (for example i need to check all checkboxed on a page)
in selenium I can do like this:

```
elements = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//xpath")
for element in elements:
    //do stuff
```

Answer (score -1):

As I understend in espresso is possible to perform only one action on one element in one time. i guess i can't get a list of elements by id or class name or whatever. so if we have container as `RecyclerView` we can perform actions on it's child elements in loop. Like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= num; i++) {
            onView(withId(R.id.result)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(i, click()));
        }
```

and we can get number of children:

```
 public int getRecyclerViewChildCount(int matcher) {
        final int[] count = {0};
        onView(withId(matcher)).perform(new ViewAction() {
            @Override
            public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
                return isAssignableFrom(RecyclerView.class);
            }
            @Override
            public String getDescription() {
                return "getting child count";
            }
            @Override
            public void perform(UiController uiController, View view) {
                RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) view;
                count[0] = rv.getChildCount();
            }
        });
        return count[0];
    }
```

but here will be the problem if, for example, we deal with search results and results are loaded in portions. So we could perform click just on first portion.

But the easier way I guess is just specify number of child elements you want perform click on and catch `PerformException` if specified number is greater:

```
try {
    int count = 50;// specify number of child elements in RecycleView you want to click
    for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++) {       
    onView(withId(R.id.result)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(i, click()));
            }
            }catch(PerformException e){}//if argument is greater then files in search result.
```